# Cannot write in text file in python program

Tags: python, class

So I am making a python game and everything in the python programs is fine except for the writing part

Here is a part of GameFile2.py:

```
class lostToss():

    def botChoose(self):
        print("Bot is choosing between batting and bowling.")
        for dot in range(5):
            print((dot + 1) * ".")
            time.sleep(0.25)
        for x in range(10):
            print("")
        choices = ['Bat', 'Bowl']
        botting = random.choice(choices)
        print(f"And the bot has chose to {botting}")
        time.sleep(1)
        if botting == "Bat":
            f = open("GamePoints.txt","w")
            with open('GamePoints.txt, 'a+') as f:
                f.write('52L05yt0smdwPMA4wgdTUF7Yh4dLT')
                print('ok')
                time.sleep(10)
                import GameFile3
        elif botting == "Bowl":
            file = open("GamePoints.txt","w+")
            with open('GamePoints.txt', 'a+') as file:
                file.write('69L05yt0smdwPMA4wgdLOL7Yh4dLT')
                time.sleep(2)
                import GameFile3
```

The problem is in the 15th and 22nd line, I ran the file many times and the "ok" text
was printed but the code couldn't be written in the file.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Missing quote in `with open('GamePoints.txt, 'a+') as f:`

Comment: Why do you have both: `f = open("GamePoints.txt","w")` and `with open('GamePoints.txt, 'a+') as f:`

Comment: I just test your code and its working fine. As @Mandera said that you have missing quote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Omit the file opening before the `with` statements. Like this

```
f = open("GamePoints.txt","w") # remove this line
with open('GamePoints.txt', 'a+') as f:
```

```
file = open("GamePoints.txt","w+") # remove this line
with open('GamePoints.txt', 'a+') as file:
```

In the first block, you are missing the closing quote after .txt.

Comment: it works now but it over writers the previous text written

Comment: the `a+` opens the file for both appending and reading. Are you sure the file already exists and has some content in it?

Comment: Yes when the GameFile2.py is imported from the first file it has a code in the txt
file which is then over written by the function

Comment: Can you make sure the file is not opened in any other part of your code in write mode?

Comment: Ok thank you, the file was open in another part of the code which I didn't close.